# Are there nonlinear differentiable functions that are positively homogeneous of order 1?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is positively homogeneous of order 1 if $f(tx) = tf(x) \quad \forall t>0$.

For instance, $f_{\alpha}(x) = \alpha x$ is a positively homogeneous funnction for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, however all such functions are linear.

Other example is $f(x)=|x|$. $f$ is not linear but also is not differentiable.

Are there any examples of $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that are positively homogeneous of order 1 and differentiable but not linear? Or can one prove that this cannot exist?

Answer (score 0):

No, on both $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ such functions are given by mappings of the form $x\mapsto\alpha x$. If now the right- and the left-derivative must coincide, the $\alpha$'s on both branches must coincide, implying that such $f$ is already linear.